# Tutorials/Resources on Developing Plug-ins for Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

can anyone point me to resources, links or tutorials on how to develop plug-ins for the Windows Mobile 6.5?

The plug-in needs to be added to the current "Today Screen" of Windows Mobile 6.5 (the scrolling, list of shortcuts/menus seen when the PDA is turned on)

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not your [personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/102937). We expect you to do your own research and then come back with specific questions based on that research. :)

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for Windows Mobile Examples pulls up this close to #1:

[Code Samples for Windows Mobile 6.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158662.aspx)

You must install the Windows Mobile 6.5 SDK, but I'd say it is your best bet.

If you like older Windows Mobile, there is also one out there for Windows Mobile 5's SDK:

[Code Samples for Windows Mobile 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms879577.aspx)